# Enviar correo con un ComboBox desde Galeria en power apps

Tags: aplicación-web, combobox, power-automate, gallery, powerapps

estoy realizando una app en power apps donde el usuario tiene que agregar el correo electronico de una persona para que le envie una invitacion, asi que cree una galeria editable y con un combo box que muestra todos los correos de una lista de  contactos de share point, la persona puede escoger el correo para enviarselo a esa persona, pero solo me gustaria que se le enviara el correo solamente donde los items contegan el correo ya que una vez que lo haya escogido se agrega a otra  lista  de invitados de share point, ya agregue esto:

```
FORALL(Gallery10.AllItems As _Mail, Office365Outlook.SendEmailV2(_Mail.Invitados, TextEmailSubject.Text, TextMessage.Text))
```

Pero estoy teniendo problemas porque esta enviando  correos a todas las personas que están en la lista de contactos de sharepoint y yo solo quiero que se envíen solamente a los que se van agregando en la galería y también en caso de que se repita el correo solamente quiero que le envié una vez el correo y no duplicados.
Se puede hacer desde power apps o tendría que realizar un flujo? No tengo experiencia en realizar flujos así que agradecería mucho que me dijeran como tengo que realizarlo.